# How can I use the square root of a number that the user enters in an input box, instead of the number itself?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an Android app, and the feature that I'm working on right now is calculating the square root of a number entered by the user.

How can I take a number that the user enters in a text box, and use the square root of that number in the `doCalc` part of my program? I'm limiting the number to be an integer between 1 and 20. For example, if the user enters `2` in the input box, I want to use `1.41` in the `doCalc` method.

Here is my .java code:

```
package learn.text;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LearntextActivity extends Activity {
    TextView text;
    EditText input;
    TextView text2;
    EditText input2;
    TextView text3;
    EditText input3;
    Button calc;
    TextView output;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Enter the design GPM for Chiller");
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        text2.setText("Enter the Square root of the actual pressure drop across the coil");
        input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input2);
        text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
        text3.setText("Enter the design pressure drop of coil");
        input3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input3);
        calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    } 
    public void doCalc (View view)  {
        double mInput = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString());
        double mInput2 = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString());
        double mInput3 = Double.parseDouble(input3.getText().toString());

        double mOutput = (mInput*mInput2)/(mInput3);
        output.setText("GPM is" + mOutput);
    }    
}
```

Here is the .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/text"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/input"></EditText>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/text2"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/input2"></EditText>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/text3"></TextView>
    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/input3"></EditText>

    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Get GPM" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/calc" android:password="false" android:onClick="doCalc"></Button>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/output"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="learn.text"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="string/app_name"> 
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LearntextActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably I'm misunderstanding something, but — can't you just change

```
Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString())
```

to

```
Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString()))
```

? (See [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29) for documentation of `Math.sqrt`.)

Comment: ruakh you did not miss anything.  Thank you for the answer.  I put it in the code and it works great! I am very new to programming.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @Droidxuser1: You're welcome! I have to say, creating an Android app seems like a very ambitious first programming project -- even going through a tutorial, as you seem to be. I wish you the best of luck with it! :-)

Comment: I like the challenge of learning new things and I needed this app on my phone for work.

Comment: @Droidxuser1: I see. Necessity is the mother of learning new skills. :-)

Comment: As I go through this learning curve would it be possible to contact you more directly when some questions arise.

Comment: @Droidxuser1: I'm a Java developer, but not an Android developer; so I probably wouldn't be able to help with a lot of your questions.